# sha1hash not working, Error in hash.

Tags: r, hash

I'm all new to hashes and encryption. What I'm trying to do is to access an API which requires hashing of some variables beforehand, now my hash somehow isn't correctly outputted.

The hash is to be in the following format:

> Hash is a sha1hash SHA1 ( CallerID + Time + key + unique) as a 40 -
>   char hexadecimal, eg " 6b76a4ede12897d42dabc2a5f9270bbdb76985af "
>   where key is the private key you assigned.

I assume the "+" signs in the text assume concatenating. Still, following the instructions and using the digest package something is wrong with my hash, although length of all variables match the instructions. Hash error is verified by using: http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/sha1-decrypter.aspx, which generated an error for my hash, also the HTTP GET query generate 403 error with hash error text.

My Code

```
library(httr)
library(digest)
library(stringi)

BooliReq  <- function() {

  #ID Info
  key  <- "PRIVATEKEY"
  caller.ID  <- "IDName"
  #//

  unix.timestamp  <- as.integer( as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) )
  random.string  <- stri_rand_strings( n = 1, length = 16)

  #Sha1-Hash: CallerID + time + key + unique, 40-char hexadecimal
  hash.string  <- paste0(caller.ID, unix.timestamp, key, random.string)  
    hash.sha1  <- digest(hash.string, "sha1")

  #Create URL
  url.string  <- paste0("https://api.booli.se/listings?q=nacka&limit=3&offset=0&callerId=", caller.ID, "&time=" , 
                        unix.timestamp, "&unique=", random.string, "&hash=", hash.sha1)

  GET(url.string, add_headers( Accept = "json"))

}
```

Link to API:

> https://translate.google.se/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=sv&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booli.se%2Fapi%2F%23pagination&edit-text=&act=url

Comment: use `digest(hash.string,"sha1",serialize=FALSE)`, but I hope that you have a real caller.ID because I doubt it will work otherwise...

Comment: Solved it! Thank you!

Comment: Please create as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `serialize=FALSE`, otherwise the input string will be first serialized and then the hash computed (so you won't get the hash of the string... check the results for example using this online sha1 generator: [link](http://www.sha1-online.com/))

```
digest(hash.string, "sha1", serialize=FALSE)
```